# GIM69207S SMP/E download fails with java.net.UnknownHostException:

Tags: networking, java, mainframe, zos, smpe

I'm in the process of downloading software to install on my z/OS system.  I've not used SMP/E Receive to download previously.

The DOWNLOAD step ends with a return code 12:

```
                                         --TIMINGS (MINS.)--            ----PAGING COUNTS---   
  STEPNAME PROCSTEP    RC   EXCP   CONN    TCB    SRB  CLOCK   SERV  PG  PAGE  SWAP   VIO SWAPS
  DOWNLOAD             12    156     11    .00    .00     .3    435   0    23     0     0     0
```

The message that is issued is:

```
GIM69207S ** GIMGTPKG PROCESSING HAS FAILED BECAUSE THE CONNECTION WITH THE   
             SERVER FAILED. java.net.UnknownHostException:                    
             some.ibm.server.ibm.com                                       
GIM20501I    GIMGTPKG PROCESSING IS COMPLETE. THE HIGHEST RETURN CODE WAS 12.
```

From TSO I can ping the hostname and it resolves correctly.

```
CS V2R3: Pinging host SOME.IBM.SERVER.IBM.COM (9.1.2.3)
 Ping #1 response took 0.034 seconds.
```

I suspect this is a CommServer configuration issue but I've not been able to find a solution via Google.

Hopefully someone can de-mystify CommServer configuration.

Note: host names and IPs changed to protect the innocent

Comment: @davidPostill . I see the question was nominated as "off-topic" . Curious what was the concern as it seems appropriate as its an administration issue.  The other venue would be ServerFault I suspect but most mainframers I've seen lurk on SO and SU.  Just trying to understand the community dynamics better.

Comment: I originally thought it was off-topic being a mainframe OS,then I checked and realised that is was on topic. Apologies, but we don't see many Z/OS questions here.